# Existence of a smooth function satisfying a condition

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

**Problem**: Let $M$ be a $n$-dimensional differentiable manifold, let $p_1,\dots, p_k\in M$ be distinct points, and let $r_1,\dots, r_k\in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary numbers. Prove that there exists a smooth function $f$ on $M$ such that $f(p_i)=r_i$ for all $i=1,\dots, k$.

**My answer**: I'm not sure. I think I should use the proposition ([Existence of Smooth Bump Functions](https://books.google.dk/books?id=eqfgZtjQceYC&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=Existence%20of%20Smooth%20Bump%20Functions&source=bl&ots=x_3-JhyZA2&sig=IA3rVuZRBGfivfwZLoPBpYkeXyQ&hl=da&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU__H1hbbYAhXFJVAKHT5BCfYQ6AEITDAC#v=onepage&q=Existence%20of%20Smooth%20Bump%20Functions&f=false)) for some case. Consider the charts $(U_i,\phi_i)$ where each $U_i$ is an open neighborhoods of $p_i$. I assume that $U_1,\dots, U_k$ are pairwise disjoint, so that for example $p_2\notin U_1$. By the proposition, there exists smooth bump function $\psi_i:M\to \mathbb{R}$. Then define $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}r_i\psi_i(x)$. Then $f$ is smooth and $f(p_i)=r_i$ as wanted. If this is correct, I presume to show the last case where $U_1,\dots, U_k$ are not pairwise disjoint, so that for example $p_2\in U_1$. I need a hand here.

Comment: You can always choose the $U_1, \dots, U_k$ so that they are disjoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your charts aren't disjoint, you can just shrink them to be disjoint!  In other words, there exist pairwise disjoint open subsets $V_i$ such that $p_i\in V_i\subseteq U_i$ for each $i$.  This is possible because $M$ is Hausdorff.  For instance, for $k=2$, since $M$ is Hausdorff there exist disjoint open sets $A$ and $B$ such that $p_1\in A$ and $p_2\in B$, and then we can take $V_1=U_1\cap A$ and $V_2=U_2\cap B$.  I'll leave it to you to work out the generalization to arbitrary $k$ (you'll just want to repeatedly use the Hausdorff axiom for different pairs of points).

Comment: What about the mapping $\phi_i$? So, what you are saying is: if $(U_1,\phi_1)$ and $(U_2,\phi_2)$ are not disjoint, there is a way to construct two charts $(V_1,\hat{\phi}_1)$ and $(V_2,\hat{\phi}_2)$ that are disjoint (because of the Hausdorffness), where $V_j\subseteq U_j$ and $\hat{\phi}_j:=\phi_j|_{V_j}$ for $j=1,2$?

Comment: That's right, you just restrict the maps.